# Como saber se ele clicou em abrir? [INPUT]

Tags: php, jquery

Bom Gente eu queria saber se existe alguma forma de saber se o usuario clicou em abrir ali, pois eu queria executar uma ação logo após isso.Meu objetivo é executar uma requisição ajax quando o cara tiver clicado em abrir... tenho um código aqui , mas ele não se adapta isso.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Basta criar um escutador para executar algum código quando o `input` for clicado e que irá abrir a janela para selecionar um arquivo:

```js
$("#file").on("click", function(){
   alert("vai abrir a janela de selecionar arquivo");
   // insira aqui o código que deseja executar
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

Comment: Mas isso vai funcionar mesmo que ele não escolha nenhum arquivo, só de clicar pra selecionar o arquivo, já vai disparar o evento. E se o usuário clicar em cancelar e não selecionar nada? Ele quer que a ação dispare só depois de clicar em abrir, então o `value` do campo `input` deixaria de ser vazio, podendo indicar que o arquivo foi selecionado, e também uma verificação pra ver se foi alterado e disparar outro evento. Pra mim essa resposta não responde a questão do AP.

Comment: A questão dele é quase igual essa do SOen [How to determine if user selected a file for file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219/how-to-determine-if-user-selected-a-file-for-file-upload)